# What does the @ macro do in a makefile?

Tags: makefile

In the below code from a `Makefile` could I ask the following two questions?

What does the `@` macro do?

Is the `sed` command replacing `\` with `//`?

```
.PHONY: prereqs
prereqs:
    (cd ../../data/ilsvrc12; make)
    @sed -i 's/\r//' run.py
    @chmod +x run.py
```

Answer (score 2):

Read [documentation of GNU `make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html). Notably its [§5.2 Recipe Echoing](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Echoing.html) which says

> Normally make prints each line of the recipe before it is executed. We call this echoing because it gives the appearance that you are typing the lines yourself.
>
> When a line starts with ‘@’, the echoing of that line is suppressed.

But notice that `@` is *not* a macro. It is part of `make`'s weird syntax.

> Is the sed command replacing \ with //?

That is covered in [sed(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sed.1.html) man page (but take into account the rules on [`bash` quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html)). So your `sed` invocation is removing occurrences of `\r` (which `sed` interprets as the return character).

BTW, you might find useful to try [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) (with `-x`) to debug your `Makefile`.

Comment: thank you for your time. If it is removing literal occurrences of `\r`, what are the `//` used for?

Comment: It is an (empty) replacement string.

Comment: To be clear, `s/X/Y/` means "for each string X substitute (s) string Y".  Here X is `\r` and Y is '' (empty string).  The `/` is a delimiter; in fact you can use any character here.  This could be written `s,\r,,` as well and it would work the same.  As above, you can find out about this in the `sed` man page or all sorts of online help for sed... Google will point you the way.

Answer (score 2):

The sed command is replacing the special character `\r` (carriage return) with an empty string... basically removing it.  This appears to be a poor-man's dos2unix implementation, converting DOS-style CRNL line ending pairs with POSIX/UNIX style NL line ending characters.

Comment: I don't think that `\r` means the carriage return here. It means the sequence of two characters backslash then r (since it is inside a shell quotation)

Comment: Yes, the shell definitely won't convert it.  But, sed will do so (maybe depending on the version of sed that you're using).  On my system, `echo 'foo\rbar' | sed 's/\r//'` generates `foo\rbar` (e.g., sed does not change it) while `echo 'foo\rbar' | sed 's/\\r//'` echoes `foobar` (e.g., escaping the backslash from sed causes it to operate on the two-character string `\r` not the special character carriage return).